Which type of visa should I apply for visiting Japan to see my girlfriend?
I'm an Indian national, and I want to visit Japan around the start of July for one or two weeks, but I am confused which type of visa would be best for me.
My scenario is that-

I am a recent graduate from one of the top Institutes of India.

I earn more than 1.5Lakhs (US$1800) a month, but I am a new earner so I don't have the latest ITR with me. I won't be able to get the form 16 from the company by then. I do have other documents though, such as a salary slip, bank statement, etc. This is the main issue!

My girlfriend stays there, and I just want to visit her actually.


I am deeply confused which visa would best suit to my case:

"Single Entry Visa for Short Stay for Indian Students"

My college is an eligible college here, and it is a relaxation for cases when someone is a student/recent graduate and can't provide financial documents. Since I don't have an ITR acknowledgement with me, I am thinking of this type of visa.
I would need to book hotels and all that, while in actuality I plan to stay at my girlfriend's house.


"Children of Individual with Sufficient financial capabilities"

Can build upon my father's financial documents?
Does anyone have any experience under this category?


"Temporary Visitor Visa"

Here the issue is that in the  ITR is clearly mentioned among the requirements, and also I would have to book hotels and all. Also, I am a solo traveller, so would it be an issue/suspicious for the embassy?


"Visiting Friends/Acquaintance"

This seems nice and relevant, and it doesn't require me to book hotels and all. Does anyone have any (positive/negative) experience with this one?



Which of these types of visa should I apply for? I don't want to get rejected.

As a general rule of thumb, honesty is the best policy when dealing with immigration. The worst that can happen if you're honest is that your visa application will be declined. The worst that can happen if you're dishonest is that your visa application will be denied and you'll earn yourself a longtime if not lifelong ban.

As an addition to @nikhil comment: We never know to which countries the visa refusal is shared, so if you are dishonest, you may get a stigma on further visa application on (western) countries: they may not trust your application. -- Just apply with the documents you have, and add a note about the reason you do not have ITR or other documents.

Yes, I understand this. I wasn't aware. Surely not gonna do anything dishonest or fake.
Please can you guys suggest which visa category should I apply. I think my main question now is whether I should apply for tourist visa or visitor visa. I mean I can actually stay in hotels if acceptance there is high. I am very skeptical whether gf/bf relationship is considered under visitor visa(especially for Japan). Also, should I take my parents as guarantor, or should I keep it self sponsored only?

@YashVerma Having a sponsor isn’t necessarily a positive. It indicates that the applicant doesn’t have sufficient resources of their own, which likely increases the visa issuer’s risk assessment of an application.See this graphic for an example of how that is likely to work

Is she Japanese ?

No, she is Indian @SaranshSharma

I understand your point @Traveller. But since I don't have proper ITR filings, I am wouldn't guarantor be a better option? Let me know your opinions please, thanks.

@YashVerma TBH (as I am very risk averse with regards to Immigration matters), if I had no travel history, wasn’t sure I have the right paperwork available and/or whether I needed a sponsor, I would have my gf come visit me in India or meet in a country you can both enter. Try reading the Japanese MoFA FAQs for insight

@YashVerma Japan has recently started the e visa. You must start somewhere apply in good faith with whatever you have. In my opinion if she is your Gf then it’s definitely a strong case for you to visit her. You don’t need a guarantor when you have a real job

Yes @SaranshSharma. I talked to a friend who had recently visited. They applied for tourist visa.. And had submitted both his own & his parent's ITR in the docs as a support. He got approved

In my opinion you could reach out a visa lawyer here you might not get best answers for your case but still try to write down and see what documents you have and what others you need and honestly you don’t need extra set of documents so just follow the embassy website requirements what they are specifically asking I have heard of people taking land related documents when it’s not even required if you are a working person so a lot of documentation is needed but not everything and I feel like you are afraid of rejection and that’s completely understandable

@SaranshSharma, yes, thanks a lot for helping!

Don’t risk a refusal by over-complicating things.
If the main purpose of your trip is to visit your gf, apply for the appropriate visa. Don’t be tempted to conceal the fact that you have a gf in Japan. Your relationship is a valid and credible reason for your trip - would you be going there at all if the relationship did not exist?
IDK about Japan specifically, but pretending you’re a regular tourist (ie no romantic links) staying in a hotel, when in reality you’re in a relationship with/staying in the home of a resident of the country, can lead to a world of immigration pain if discovered.

on arrival would you lie outright to the Immigration Officer if he/she asks where you’re staying? If Japanese hotels have to register foreign guests with the authorities, the hotel might report your booking no-show.
during your stay, your lie could come to light if for any reason you attract the attention of the Japanese authorities
after your visit, if eg you do want a visa to stay with your gf in future you won’t be able to tell the truth about your previous stay.

Best to tell the truth rather than risk being caught out in a lie that could result in a ban and/or come back to haunt you in the future. IDK about Japan specifically, however there are examples on TSE of approved visas having been revoked as a result of the authorities becoming aware that the visa holder cancelled the hotel booking after getting the visa ie intentionally misrepresented the visit plans. You can of course amend your travel plans but the arrangements should not be materially different.

I think there has been some misinterpretation. I won't be faking hotels, I am planning of actually booking them but can cancel afterwards. Is this also a wrong thing?
I wasn't aware of this being dishonest.. Will not do it at all if thats the case!

@YashVerma - it sounds pretty dishonest to me, and I suspect to most people. Don't do it. "Visiting Friends/Acquaintance" sounds like the honest approach.

Sure, I agree with your point. My only question is whether I should mention of her being my gf or should I just mention her as one of my friends?
I haven't heard any cases of visiting visa for gf/bf relationships, Hence asking for suggestions!
Thanks in advance!

IDK about Japan, but IIRC there are questions on TSE about approved visas having been revoked as a result of the authorities becoming aware that the visa holder cancelled the hotel booking after getting the visa ie intentionally misrepresented the visit plans. You can of course amend your travel plans but the arrangements should remain broadly similar. Changing from a hotel to staying with a friend is materially different.

@YashVerma if you have a travel history then you should apply the visa to visit your gf. Don’t feel bad about applying tourist visa or visitor it’s all the same as long as you have an honest intention to come back to India.

@Yash Japan doesn't particularly inquiry as to the specific relationship you have with that person. There's a spousal relationship, which is important, and anything else falls in the "friend/acquaintance" category. It doesn't matter whether it's a high school buddy or your possible future wife. If actually asked, sure, tell them she's your girlfriend. But it's not a separate visa category or different reason to visit.

@SaranshSharma, No I don't have any travel history.
This along with the fact that ITR is not with me are making me super anxious if I should apply & what should be the right category!

Yeah I understand that its not a separate visa category. But are there any acceptance chances for such cases? When there's invite just from a friend/gf. Who is not even family/blood-relative. Never heard of any cases like these. Please let me know your opinon/experiences @deceze. Thanks!

@Yash I don't know what the situation is for Indians per se. If Japan does offer "visiting friends and relatives" as a viable visa category for you and you fit that definition, then go for it. No need to think about any other categories unless you somehow don't fulfil the requirements for that category and need to think about alternatives.

@YashVerma you could use salary slips stamped ones and proof of employment. Bank statements would also do . You are unnecessarily freaking out

@YashVerma "When there's invite just from a friend/gf. Who is not even family/blood-relative." ... FWIW, I applied for a short-term visa for my wife before our marriage (so when we were only engaged) so that she could come to Japan immediately after our marriage without waiting for a dependent visa. We also made a similar application for Schengen visas for a honeymoon trip. Japan accepted, EU rejected. I also know of a friend whose fiance visited him in Tokyo before marriage but I'm not sure what visa type they used.

"Your relationship is a valid and credible reason for your trip" - is it? A girlfriend is not a mere acquintance or a distant relative, whom one would visit occasionally. The authorities may interpret such a relationship as a quite high risk of overstaying.

@TrangOul Indeed, however it does explain why someone with no travel history has chosen Japan as their first ever trip abroad. I doubt Japan is a first-choice destination for would-be overstayers.

@SaranshSharma Right, I am thinking about it too, Its just that few people I knew of who applied for visas told me that Japanese visa relies heavily on ITR and all. This has made me worried

@TrangOul, If that's the case, then, does it mean that any unmarried-couple have somewhat greater chances of getting rejected? What should be the right thing then according to you?

@YashVerma I really don’t think your having a gf in Japan is a big dealbreaker provided you can tick all the other boxes eg good ties to home country. You’ll tie yourself up in knots seeking advice / experiences from strangers on the internet, when the truth is that no-one can tell you what your chances are. You just have to put together the strongest application you can, and hope for a positive outcome.

Yes, I understand that @Traveller.
I am getting confused, but I just really don't want to get rejected!

@YashVerma Of course. Don’t forget that the majority of visa applicants actually do get their visa, there are a lot of horror stories but that’s because only unsuccessful applicants post about it!
